# Databricks: copy plots styles

Tags: plot, databricks

I'd like to copy plots styles between cells. It's possible to this or I need to click plot button and configure keys, values and series in each cell?

EDITED:
The idea is just use same plot that I used in the cell before with code, not entering in "plot options" and adding axes and series "manually".

[image]
Thanks!

Comment: what did you already try? Show some code, work done.

Comment: I edited my initial comment. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no option to copy plot options between cells in a Notebook.

Currently, you need to do it manually for every cell.

"You can click the down arrow next to the bar chart Chart Button to choose another chart type and click Plot Options… to configure the chart."

For more details, refer "[Azure Databricks - Visualizations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/notebooks/visualizations/)"

I would suggest you to provide feedback on the same:

https://feedback.azure.com/forums/909463-azure-databricks

http://feedback.databricks.com/forums/263785-product-feedback

All of the feedback you share in these forums will be monitored and reviewed by the Microsoft engineering teams responsible for building Azure.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks! an alternative is copy all the cell. This maintains the plot format  and the keys used.